# Why cannot I return string in c++

Tags: c++

```
int convertWord(string data, string type){
    int length=data.length();
    if(type=="input"){
        for(int a=0; a<length; a++){
            if (data[a]==' '){
                data[a]='_';
            }
        }
    }
    if(type=="output"){
        for(int a=0; a<length; a++){
            if (data[a]=='_'){
                data[a]=' ';
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

I got `cannot convert std::string to int in return` error message.

Comment: Did your compiler complain? What did it complain?

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature says `convertWord` returns an `int`, then you try and return a `std::string`. Correct your signature like this:

```
string convertWord(string data, string type){
//^^^^ string instead of int
```